# Correct way of annotation-caching with multiple entry points

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am starting to use JSR 107/Spring cache annotations. I am preferring JSR annotation over Spring-specific for the moment, simply because they are *standard*-ish.

I have a lookup entity that I can query and modify in different ways. The concept is that I want to cache data found on database **at least until someone makes *any* change**. "Any" is good for me.

Let me simplify the concept: I have this entity named `ApplicationProperty` which rarely (if not never) changes, and I want to cache it in its manager. The following is a **simplified version**

```
@Entity
public class ApplicationProperty {

    @Id
    private String key;

    @Column
    private String valueSerialized;

    @Column
    private Class<?> type;
}
```

The `ApplicationPropertyManager` takes complete care of both **(de)serialization** and **validation**, and I have written and tested it in order to make database calls. Works fine. Let us see the methods I can use now, but before that please consider I can basically allow the front end to view/edit all the properties **or** a developer using my code to read/edit a single property.

Also, for the joy

```
public interface ApplicationPropertyManager {

    /**
    * Key is the property's ID, value is automagically deserialized
    * Preferred way to display all properties to front end screen via AJAX
    */
    Map<String, ? extends Serializable> getApplicationPropertyValues();

    /**
    * Preferred way to get a property programmatically. It is automagically casted by code
    */
    <T extends Serializable> T getApplicationProperty(String propertyId);

    /**
    * Preferred way to set a property programmatically. Username is for audit and is irrelevant to caching
    */
    void setApplicationProperty(String propertyId, Serializable value, String username);

    /**
    * Front end sets all properties at once in a single transaction. Username is for audit and is irrelevant to caching
    */
    void setApplicationProperties(Map<String, ? extends Serializable> properties, String username);
}
```

Having said this, I have failed in **understanding** how caching annotations in Spring work in [non-trivial cases](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/). My goal is that the cache behaves as just a local `Map<String,Serializable>`.

1. When I retrieve a single value (after attempting to run the database the first time) it is retrieved cached
2. When I retrieve all the values, I can run the database once and continue then to return cached values
3. Editing a single value should **at very least** invalidate cache for

   - getApplicationProperty(String value) invoked with the propert key
   - getApplicationProperties() in all cases
4. Editing all values with the multi-value edit method must invalidate all caching of this entity and return to use the database at least once.

I have tried to annotate `@CacheResult(cacheName = VALUES_CACHE_NAME)` the getters and `@CachePut(cacheName = VALUES_CACHE_NAME)` both setters. However running the application resulted in the cache being always invoked, and modifications not visible by the AJAX call.

I am in the process of writing an extensive set of unit tests to replicate the cases, but I still fail in understand how my annotations should be designed.

My scenario differs from trivial examples because:

- We are not just talking of a plain collection of `Book`s: entities are transformed and processed
- The cache once works with the entire set of entities, and the other time with sub-sets taken from database.

How should I handle caching in this scenario? I don't need extreme performance, I am also happy if Spring clears the entire cache after editing a single value. Otherwise I would need to rollback to plain cache management, losing the benefit of `@Cache` annotation preventing transaction execution.